# Настройка отображения календаря в Android приложении

Tags: android

Суть проблемы заключается в следующем: в приложении необходимо реализовать календарь с событиями, но по умолчанию он находится в частично свернутом виде (отображается только одна неделя, т.е. семь дат горизонтально одна за другой  и название месяца над ними, недели можно пролистать свайпами), прочитал документацию по CalendarView, посмотрел другие реализации календарей, но ни где не могу найти решение этого вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно конечно поковыряться и найти решение с встроенным `CalendarView` но на мой взгляд проще найти нормальную библиотеку которая будет в разы лучше чем встроенный виджет. Вот например есть [такая](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview) библиотека. Здесь вы сможете настроить полностью все что вам нужно:

```
mcv.state().edit()
  .setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.WEDNESDAY)
  .setMinimumDate(CalendarDay.from(2016, 4, 3))
  .setMaximumDate(CalendarDay.from(2016, 5, 12))
  .setCalendarDisplayMode(CalendarMode.WEEKS)
  .commit();
```

более подробно в документации. [Вот](https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Calendar) есть проект календаря где можно все самому посмотреть как работает и взять то что нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть [куча](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27) библиотек для реализации того что вам нужно или [вот](https://medium.com/@Patel_Prashant_/android-custom-calendar-with-events-fa48dfca8257) еще источник. Надеюсь вам что-то из всего предложенного подойдет.